# Facebook gives me error when trying to generate code

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

I want to post to my facebook wall via the api/php. Im following steps found via google.

So the first step was to log into facebook, create an app to get the appid. I did that, it then says to go here: https://login.facebook.com/code_gen.php?api_key=APIKEY&v=1.0 so I can generate the code so you can go to the next step. I replace APIKEY with the api key from the app I just created and everytime I try to go to that url I get the error:

An error occurred. Please try again later.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you're providing the right API key? I went to that link and entered an API key and I generated a code without a problem. Are you logged into facebook as the account that own the application?

Comment: Yes Im positive Im using the correct api key. I am logged into facebook as the account that owns the application but I tried using another facebook account and received the same error.

Comment: I do see this in the url though: http://www.facebook.com/code_gen.php?api_key=apikeyientered&v=1.0&error_code=101&error_msg=Invalid+API+key But dont know how this is. When I go see my apps right there on the front page it says API Key and I copy and paste that into the url and get this darn error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I decided to go a different route, I used the graph api for Facebook instead of the original way I was going. Here is a link that helped me figure it out:

[Oath2 Facebook Example](http://kartiklad.com/oauth-2-0-and-graph-api-for-facebook-canvas-applications/)